# .NET equivalent to java.util.Arrays.hashCode() function for arrays of intrinsic types?

Tags: java, .net, arrays, hashcode, gethashcode

Is there a.NET utility class equivalent to [java.util.Arrays.hashCode()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode(int[])) for arrays of intrinsic types such as int[], short[], float[], etc.?

Obviously I could write my own utility class but was trying to find one already available in the .NET framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET 4.0 arrays will support this via the [IStructuralEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.istructuralequatable%28VS.100%29.aspx) interface, but until that point you'll have to do it yourself I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there's nothing in the framework itself that does this. There may well be some third-party implementations, but there's nothing built-in (and public).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such a thing being built-into .Net up to version 3.5, although .Net 4 is very likely to support it natively via the [IStructuralEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.istructuralequatable%28VS.100%29.aspx) interface which `Array` will implement (thanks to Greg Beech for pointing that out).

Here's a simple implementation using an extension method on IEnumerable.

```
int HashContents<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    int hash = 0x218A9B2C;
    foreach (var item in enumerable)
    {
        int thisHash = item.GetHashCode();
        //mix up the bits.
        hash = thisHash ^ ((hash << 5) + hash);
    }
    return hash;
}
```

This will give different hashcodes for `{0,0}` and `{0,0,0}`.

Comment: Two quick questions: 1) Is it really faster to do the shift and add rather than just multiply?  2) As far as I can tell, if the value of thisHash is always zero, then the final hash will be zero, no matter how many items.  This seems to contradict your last sentence.

Comment: 1) In Release mode, VS2008, my micro-benchmarks indicate the shift-and-add version peforms about 8% faster than the equivalent multiplication. 2) Thanks, code has been fixed.